# How to change/format the value in props input from react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, react-final-form

In an edit form my API returns an array of ids `[ 1, 2 ]` to display advertisers in inputs, I used `react-select` for the for autocomplete but `react-select` needs : `[{label: 'foo', value: 1}, {label: 'bar', value: 2}]`.

I get the labels in my component via a fetch and I would like to know how to change the values in `react-final-form` to have the right format.

Here is my EditForm :

```
const AgenciesInputs = ({
  getMany,
  record,
  sourceAdvertisers,
  sourceCreatedBy,
  sourceIsActive,
  sourceName,
  translate,
}) => {
  const [formatedAdvertisers, setFormatedAdvertisers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { advertisers } = record;

    getMany(ADVERTISERS, advertisers, ({ payload: { data } }) =>
      setFormatedAdvertisers(data.map(({ id, name }) => ({ value: id, label: name }))),
    );
  }, []);

  console.log(formatedAdvertisers);

  return (
    <Root id="SLM_agenciesInputs">
      <TextInput autoFocus label="agencies_name" source={sourceName} validate={required()} />
      {!isNilOrEmpty(record) && (
        <TextInput
          disabled
          format={record => (record ? `${record.lastname} ${record.firstname}` : '')}
          label="agencies_createdBy"
          source={sourceCreatedBy}
        />
      )}
      <BooleanInput defaultValue label="agencies_isActive" source={sourceIsActive} />

      <Field
        component={CustomAutoCompleteInput}
        id="SLM_avertisersInput"
        minLength={1}
        name={sourceAdvertisers}
        placeholder={translate('agencies_advertisers')}
        url={sourceAdvertisers}
        validate={required()}
        isMulti
      />
    </Root>
  );
};


export default AgenciesInputs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an `options` prop, it will be passed along to `CustomAutoCompleteInput` just like `placeholder` and `isMulti` are. Seems like you could just pass `options={formatedAdvertisers}`.